# How do i read data of a 24bit BMP file using C++ without any libraries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap, bmp

I am trying to read the data part of a 24bit BMP file. But after the read is complete when the image is processed, I am getting the output upside down. Whenever I try and send the data in reverse I am getting the image flipped horizontally.

This is the code I am using to read the data.

```
iPacketSize = ((320*240)/128);

fp = fopen(StrFullFilePath,"rb");

unsigned char info[54];

// read the 54-byte header

fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fp); 

// extract image height and width from header

int width = *(int*)&info[18];

int height = *(int*)&info[22];

// allocate 3 bytes per pixel

int size = (height * ( width * ( 24 / 8 )));

unsigned char* data_pix = new unsigned char[size];

unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size];

// read the rest of the data at once

fread(data_pix, sizeof(unsigned char), size, fp); 

fclose(fp);

unsigned char tmp;

//Converting BGR to RGB

for(i = 0; i < size; i += 3)
{
   tmp = data_pix[i];

    data_pix[i] = data_pix[i + 2];

    data_pix[i + 2] = tmp;
} 

//taking avg of RBG val

for(j=0;j<76800;j++)
{
    data[j] = ((data_rev[i] + data_rev[i+1] + data_rev[i+2])/3);

    i=i+3;
}
```

I want to know which process I am doing wrong; is it in data read or BGR to RGB conversion.
from what I have understood I guess I am doing the BGR to RGB conversion wrong and I think there should be two loops for doing the same.
If anyone has sample code or know about this issue please help me.

Comment: Yes, bitmaps with a positive height have the bottom row first in the file. This is documented. You need to rearrange the rows (but not the columns!) yourself.

Comment: You used `data_rev`, which is not declared here.

Comment: well i have removed the rev code as it was not working ; what i did is i took the buffer after all BGR to RGB conversions and sent the buffer from last to first .

Comment: so should i rearrange the data first and then convert BGR to RGB ?? could someone share a sample code regarding this please .

Comment: Read a line from the file into temporary buffer, write it to the correct place in your output buffer while byteswapping. Or just use stb_image, which is header-only and solves all this for you.